# Shell Script SCP Return Code 1

Tags: shell

I am using shell script scp command to move one file from one server to another using ssh.
My command looks like this:

```
scp -P 23 -i $TEST_SSHKEY $DESTINATION_PATH/$FILETOCOPY $USER_ID@$SERVER_BOX:
```

File is copying but scp is returning return code as 1.

Why it is happening and what is the solution for this?

Comment: Your line seems OK. Return code 1 is a generic error about options/params. As the command works it's strange ... Post a bit more of your shell script it might help ...

Answer (score 1):

G'day,

Try enabling verbose mode (-v) to see more details of what's going on rather than just looking at a return code of 1 which means "something bad happened".

Comment: Thanks for your responses but verbose output is returning -1 exit status.

Comment: @prathibha, have you tried the other forms of the command? ssh -P 23 -i .... -2 to use protocol 2 only? or try specifiying the user as -l <user> <host> instead of <user>@<host>

Answer (score 1):

I have this same issue. The problem is the server on the remote end not sending an exit code. Compare these transaction excerpts.

The first causes `$? = 1`:

```
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -f /cfg/running-config
Sink: C0644 3398 running-config
running-config                                     100% 3398     3.3KB/s   00:00    
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Connection to xxxxx closed by remote host.
Transferred: sent 2576, received 5216 bytes, in 1.9 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 1346.9, received 2727.3
debug1: Exit status -1
```

The second causes `$?=0`:

```
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -f /cfg/running-config
Sink: C0644 3940 running-config
running-config                                     100% 3940     3.9KB/s   00:00    
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Connection to xxxxx closed by remote host.
Transferred: sent 2624, received 5984 bytes, in 1.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 2026.8, received 4622.2
```

These are two HP switches on different firmware versions. The first one is very old; the second one is new and correctly returns `exit-status reply 0` to the client.